# How to allow EditText to be empty and show setError message?

Tags: java, android

For many days now, I have been struggling to understand why the help that I found online didn't solve my issue, so I thought my best bet would be to ask here.

As a side note, I'm aware that my variable names aren't the best,and I am in general a newbie when it gets to Android development, but I think I can understand and I'm able sort issues fairly easily - except perhaps this thing.

I'm creating a simple app that allows me to get the total of profits of an item sold, so it would take the shipping price into consideration and do the calculation automatically. For this, when the shipping price would be left empty (blank), I would want to return a message saying it can't be empty, and a '0' must be entered to do the calculation. (My EditText field only allows numbers to be entered)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
double shippingNum;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

shippingPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shippingPrice);
}

calculateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

shippingNum = Integer.parseInt(shippingPrice.getText().toString());
if(shippingPrice.getText().toString().equals("") || 
shippingPrice.getText().length() == 0){
                //shippingPrice.setText("0");
                shippingPrice.setError("You can't leave this field empty! Enter something!");
            }
```

I have also tried other variations such as:

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(shippingPrice.getText().toString().trim())){
                shippingPrice.setError("You can't leave this field empty! Enter something!");
                shippingPrice.setText("0");
            }
```

But none of these seem to have allow me to leave the field empty without crashing. I've tried a dozen of different methods which I have realised that they were a waste of time as they wouldn't work - at least I've learned where I can use them.

Any help is much appreciated and thank you.

Comment: Add crash your logs

Comment: Can you share crash logs

Comment: your code looks wrong! where is `calculateBtn` initialization? your `setOnClickListener` is outside `onCreate`. this code `shippingNum = Integer.parseInt(shippingPrice.getText().toString());` should be `shippingNum = Double.parseDouble(shippingPrice.getText().toString());`

Comment: May be you are getting crash because of `shippingPrice.setError`. Use Toast instead. And can you please post your logcat.

Comment: did you try to debug where is it getting crashed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try just doing, check the length of the edit text, if zero display a toast saying enter more if not do the next part of the program:

```
if(getText().length() == 0){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Enter values into field!",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else{
    // continue with the desired function of the program
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that did the trick for me. It's hard to believe that this small issue took me far too long to realise... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Add this below method in your class :

```
 public static boolean checkBlankValidation(EditText editText) {
     if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText().toString().trim())) {
         return false;
     } else {
         return true;
     }
 }
```

And call this method like below :

```
 if (!checkBlankValidation(shippingPrice)) {
      shippingPrice.requestFocus();
      Toast.makeText(this, "Field should not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      return false;
 } else {
      return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
                editText.setError("This Field is required");
                editText.requestFocus();

            } else
                editText.setError(null);


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
}
```

}